# Android Studio on RPi4

Tags: pi-4, android

So with the release of the 4GB version of Raspberry Pi 4 I started wondering whether installing and running Android Studio on it will be possible. Previous Pi versions were lacking in terms of RAM even when it came to minimal requirements. The 4 GB version meets the current minimum, but will it be possible to actually write anything on it?

Comment: Is there an ARM version of Android Studio?

Comment: The fact that there is a singular "Chrome OS" build implies AS isn't that specific platform wise, since chromebooks are heterogeneous (ARM and x64) -- although I think most people who use it on a chromebook use crostini (= no ARM) and the linux build.   The *recommended* minimum is actually **8** GB...

Comment: I know that the recommended is 8 GB, but I saw people complaining about AS even when having more RAM, so my question is more of "does it even have a chance to run without crashing every five minutes?" than "is RPi going to fulfill all of my expectations?"

Comment: Tried getting it running. First issue is a VM option, ConnMarkGc, remove that line from `bin/studio64.vmoptions`. Then there will be issues with the SDk manager. An...@google.com is working on it... andi? https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/168091531